# Join 3 tables and return unique/distinct rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables in SQL Server Database.
I want to fetch the **`distinct/unique`** rows When I join these 3 tables.

For this I am using `distinct` keyword after `SELECT` query but its not working.
It still return repeated records in `SELECT` query (i.e., `ID, Column1, Column2` all records are repeating since duplicate records already exist in 1 of the 3 tables)

Please let me know how to join 3 tables and return `unique/distinct` rows.
Please reply

**Edit:** Below is my current query along with result set:

[image]

Please check the returned result. It has duplicate records in it.

**Edit 2:**
Really sorry for above confusion. Please check this section:

If suppose one of the Join table gives me below result set (Ignore Yellow text for now):
[image]

**Requirement:**

Now, I want to SELECT records in below format from above result set:

- If any RequestID (exaple: ABC123)/BarcodeNo (example: B1) has Action
  = Save & Submit together then only `Action = Submit` record/row shall display in SELECT query.
- If any RequestID (example: XYZ678)/BarcodeNo (example: B22) has
  Action = Save & Submit & Resubmit (multiple Resubmit) together, etc
  then only `Action = Latest Resubmit` (among multiple Resubmit)
  record/row shall display in SELECT query.
- If any RequestID (example: GHI987)/BarcodeNo (example: B3) has Action
  = Submit & Resubmit (multile Resubmit) together, etc then only `Action = Latest Resubmit` (among multiple Resubmit) record/row shall display in SELECT query.
- If any RequestID (example: PQR902)/BarcodeNo (example: B44) has
  Action = Submit & Resubmit together, etc then only `Action = Resubmit`
  record/row shall display in SELECT query.
- If any RequestID (example: TTT878)/BarcodeNo (example: B5) has Action
  = Submit alone, etc then only `Action = Submit` record/row shall display in SELECT query.

Above "etc" means, Actions *other than* 'Save' , 'Submit' , 'Resubmit'

To fulfill above requirement (Yellow Text, based on above requirement), I tried below query:

```
Select distinct R.RequestID, R.BarcodeNo, W.Action, W.CreatedDate 
 INTO #TempTable

 From [Sunway_AP].[Invoice].[tbl_Request] (NOLOCK) R
 Left Join [Sunway_AP].[Invoice].[tbl_Xml](NOLOCK) X On X.XmlID = R.XmlID
 Left Join [Sunway_AP].[Invoice].[tbl_WorkflowHistory] (NOLOCK) W On W.RequestID = R.RequestID
 order by R.RequestID

SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT distinct * FROM (SELECT distinct *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY RequestID ORDER BY CreatedDate desc) RowNumber FROM #TempTable 
    WHERE [Action] = 'Resubmit') AS t
    WHERE RowNumber = 1

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT distinct * FROM (SELECT distinct *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY RequestID ORDER BY CreatedDate desc) RowNumber FROM #TempTable
    WHERE [Action] = 'Save' 
    AND RequestID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT RequestID FROM #TempTable WHERE [action] = 'Submit')
    AND RequestID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT RequestID FROM #TempTable WHERE [action] = 'Resubmit')) AS t
    WHERE RowNumber = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT distinct * FROM (SELECT distinct *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY RequestID ORDER BY CreatedDate desc) RowNumber FROM #TempTable
    WHERE [Action] = 'Submit' 
    AND RequestID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT RequestID FROM #TempTable WHERE [action] = 'Resubmit')) AS t
    WHERE RowNumber = 1
) AS a 
order by RequestID
```

but it does not give me expected result.
Please let me know what shall I change in my query to get the desired output ?

Comment: Please post your query

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673225/distinct-rows-from-three-tables-using-joins

Comment: What does your question have to do with C#? And what DBMS are you using (MySQL, SQL Server, Postgres, ...)?

Comment: Again: Please post your query. And please show us two rows your are getting that you consider duplicate.

Comment: Are you joining the tables in the query ?   Or do you want to combine the result sets from the tables ? For the latter you need to use Union.  Distinct will only work on each data set separately.

Comment: @All: Please re check my posted question. I had updated it along with query and returned result set. Please reply

Comment: Don't you think copying and pasting the query as text is more easier than posting screenshot?

Comment: @RagingBull: Sorry for that. Please ignore that mistake and please suggest some solution. Please reply

Comment: They are not really duplicates. The combination is unique if you include `action` column. what about that column?

Comment: I don't see any duplicates either. There are not two rows where RequestID, BarcodeNo and Action are the same.

Comment: @All: I am really sorry for the confusion. Please check the **Edit 2** section in  my posted question. Please help me to solve the issue. Please reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not really distinct rows from a given dataset you are after, so DISTINCT doesn't work for you. Rather you want a ranking of your records and only display the "best" for a given requestid / barcodeno combination. In SQL you'd rank them with ROW_NUMBER(), giving the best record row_number #1, the second best #2, and so on. Then you only keep #1's and that's it.

In your case (with `>` meaning "preferred"): recent Resubmit > earlier Resubmit > Submit > Save

```
select requestid, barcodeno, action, createddate
from
(
  select 
    r.requestid, 
    r.barcodeno,
    w.action,
    w.createddate,
    row_number() over 
    (
      partition by requestid, barcodeno
      order by
      case w.action 
        when 'Save' then 1
        when 'Submit' then 2
        when 'Resubmit' then 3
        else 0
      end desc, w.createddate desc
    ) as rn
  from tbl_request r
  join tbl_xml x on x.xmlid = r.xmlid
  join tbl_workflowhistory w on w.requestid = x.requestid
) ranked
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried your query and its working fine **but it is also fetching 1 more action, other than "Save, Submit, Resubmit"** i.e, `Cancel IPR` action. I only want to fetch Action = Save, Submit, Resubmit based on your defined preference. Please let me know why is this happening. Please reply

Comment: If you want to exclude actions from your result, use a **WHERE** clause. E.g. `where w.action <> 'Cancel IPR'` or `where w.action in ('Save','Submit','Resubmit')`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Using this condition: `Where rn=1 AND w.Action in ('Save','Submit','Resubmit')` your query working fine. Thanks

Comment: I am glad it's working for you. I would have put the WHERE condition in the subselect (after the last join), so as to exclude records right away before ranking them . No big difference, it may be a tad faster, that's all.

Comment: Thanks you for the help Mr. Thorsten Kettner :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you report show "Duplicates" is because your action column 
is making the first two columns to be repeated, because thers different actions on those codes all of them are displayed multiple times for the multiple actions
if you remove the action column you will see only one line for each code

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I am really sorry for the confusion. Please check the **Edit 2** section in  my posted question. Please help me to solve the issue. Please reply